# Trouble with Qt QCanBus filters

Tags: qt, filter, can-bus

I'm trying to use the QCanBus filters (Qt version 6.4.0) like so:

```
if (QCanBus::instance()->plugins().contains(QStringLiteral("vectorcan"))) {
        QString errorString = QString("Error");
        canDevice = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(QStringLiteral("vectorcan"), QStringLiteral("can0"), &errorString);
        if (!canDevice)
        {
            qDebug() << "Error: " << errorString << Qt::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            QCanBusDevice::Filter filter;
            QList<QCanBusDevice::Filter> filterList;

            filter.frameId = 0x18FFC281;
            filter.frameIdMask = 0x00FFFFFF;
            filter.format = QCanBusDevice::Filter::MatchExtendedFormat;
            filter.type = QCanBusFrame::DataFrame;
            filterList.append(filter);

            //apply filter
            canDevice->setConfigurationParameter(QCanBusDevice::RawFilterKey, QVariant::fromValue(filterList));

            //set baud rate
            canDevice->setConfigurationParameter(QCanBusDevice::BitRateKey, QVariant(250000));

            bool connected = canDevice->connectDevice();
            if (connected)
            {
                connect(canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, this, &CANHandler::ProcessFramesReceived);
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "Error connecting to device." << Qt::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting this only let messages through that match the filter, yet when I print the ID of incoming messages, it seems no filtering is happening:

```
void CANHandler::ProcessFramesReceived()
{
    while(canDevice->framesAvailable())
    {
        QCanBusFrame frame = canDevice->readFrame();
        qDebug() << QString::number(frame.frameId(), 16) << Qt::endl;
        //every CAN message on the bus appears here
    }
}
```

Am I using the filter wrong? Do I have the wrong expectation?

EDIT: After looking into the documentation further I realized the Vector plugin does not actually support filtering at the time of this post. I'm not exactly sure as to why, seems like only a few plugins offered by Qt support filtering.

Comment: I interpret the manual the same way, and have the same result.  Hoping someone with QCanBusDevice experience will chime in.  Even with the default filter, or no filter, every frame ID seems to be accepted.